# How to pass an array type object as empty string array instead of NULL?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

I have a checklist comboxbox in vb.net. If I don't select any value it goes as NULL but I want to sent it as empty string array.

I did this.

```
For Each checkedMP In chkListMaintenancePlant.CheckedItems
    listMaintenance.Add(checkedMP)
Next

If listMaintenance.Count > 0 Then
    MyMEqRequest.MaintenancePlant = listMaintenance.ToArray()
Else
    Dim empty() As String = {}
    MyMEqRequest.MaintenancePlant = empty
End If
```

It goes to else part but still **NULL**.

`MaintenancePlant` is of type string array  `Public Property MaintenancePlant() As String()`

Comment: Why do you say `empty` is `NULL`. It's an emtpy string array, containing no element, but it is not `Null`.

Comment: what are you doing when you get the NULL result on MyMEqRequest.MaintainancePlant? does it throw an error on the line shown when you assign empty() to it? or do you get NULL when trying to retrieve the value of MaintainencePlant later?